# User Location Focus SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, core-location

I'm trying to program a ToDo app and want to design the whole thing as a map on which the individual points on the ToDo list are displayed as pins and an event should be carried out every time one of these pins is reached. To test the whole thing, I took a GPS track that is supposed to simulate a bus ride and feeds my app with GPS data. The individual points are on this GPS track.

My app has a button that, when you press it, always focuses on the user location. The problem is he always focuses on the starting point of the GPS track and not on the current location of the GPS track.

Would be very grateful for help!

This is the focus function and the location update function

```
@Published var region : MKCoordinateRegion!

func focusLocation() {
        
   guard let _ = region else{return}
        
   mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
   mapView.setVisibleMapRect(mapView.visibleMapRect, animated: true)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
   guard let location = locations.last else{return}
   self.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 10000, 
   longitudinalMeters: 10000)
        
   self.mapView.setRegion(self.region, animated: true)
   self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(self.mapView.visibleMapRect, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this when you press the button, given you have the coordinates to focus on:

```
func focusLocation(gotoLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let rangeInMeters: Double = 10000   // <-- adjust as desired
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: gotoLocation,
                                                   latitudinalMeters: rangeInMeters,
                                                   longitudinalMeters: rangeInMeters)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}
```